# Why doesn't this JSON validate against this schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

**user_definition.json**

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "user": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "first_name": { "type": "string" },
        "last_name":  { "type": "string" },
        "email":      { "type": "email" }
      },
      "required": ["first_name", "last_name", "email"]
    }
  }
}
```

**user_schema.json**

```
{
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "../definitions/user_definition.json#/definitions/user" },
    {
      "properties": {
        "id":         { "type": "string" },
        "created_at": { "type": "date-time" },
        "updated_at": { "type": "date-time" }
      },
      "required": ["id", "created_at", "updated_at"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "id":"f10b9c6e-695c-11e5-bf98-c7cb6d8af9eb",
  "first_name":"Johanna",
  "last_name":"Littel",
  "email":"ora_turcotte@ratke.net",
  "created_at":"2015-10-02T23:26:00.663Z",
  "updated_at":"2015-10-02T23:26:00.663Z"
}
```

I get the following error when I validate the document against the schema:

```
expected

{"id":"f10b9c6e-695c-11e5-bf98-c7cb6d8af9eb","first_name":"Johanna","last_name":"Littel","email":"ora_turcotte@ratke.net","created_at":"2015-10-02T23:26:00.663Z","updated_at":"2015-10-02T23:26:00.663Z"}

to match schema "user_response":

       {
         "allOf": [
           { "$ref": "../definitions/user_definition.json#/definitions/user" },
           {
             "properties": {
               "id":         { "type": "string" },
               "created_at": { "type": "date-time" },
               "updated_at": { "type": "date-time" }
             },
             "required": ["id", "created_at", "updated_at"]
           }
         ]
       }
```

I know it's pulling in the definition because if I make the ref invalid it will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that your schema is invalid.  `date-time` and `email` are not valid values for the `type` keyword.  You will need to do something like the following instead.

```
{ "type": "string", "format": "date-time" }
```

and

```
{ "type": "string", "format": "email" }
```

Comment: If I throw everything into the schema and remove the $ref both email and date-time validate correctly.

Comment: When I replace both email and date-time with string the error continues to happen.

Comment: Based on that information, it sounds undeniable that your `$ref` is not resolving properly.  How that is resolved will depend on the specific library you are using, so I can't help there.

Comment: It sounds like the validator you are using doesn't follow the JSON specification if it doesn't complain that your schema is invalid.  It most definitely is.  I can confirm for you that if you make the changes in my answer, your schema is a perfectly valid JSON Schema.

Comment: You should run your schemas through an online validator to make sure they are good since you can't seem to be able to trust the validator you are using.  This one is best http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/.  But this one has a much more pleasant to use interface http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/#